# HTML5 SSE In Grails

Tags: javascript, html, grails, server-push

I was trying to use HTML5 SSE in grails app. Following is example code in action:

```
def push(){
    println "Inside action..."
    response.setContentType("text/event-stream");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    render("data: ${System.currentTimeMillis()}");
}
```

Client-side code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
        var source = new EventSource("push");
        source.onmessage = function(event) {
            console.debug("event triggered...");
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
        };
        source.onerror = function(event) {
            console.log(event.message);
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
    }
</script>
```

But the onmessage event is not getting triggered. onerror gets triggered and prints undefined.It hits the correct action but does not stream data.

I also tried :

```
response.outputStream.write(...........)
response.outputStream.flush()
```

but doesn't work.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Well,  I solved it. I used :

```
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    writer.write("data:"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"\n\n")
```

and it worked.

Comment: Hello Vivek, how did you manage to flush the data and avoid the connection from being closed after the controller/action is finished?